Proving equivalent conditions for an automorphism to lie in the $i^{th}$ ramification group.
I am following these notes on the Kronecker-Weber Theorem and it quotes without proof the following equivalences.
Below, $K$ is a number field, $\mathfrak{p}$ is a prime ideal in the ring of integers $\mathcal{O}_K$, $\mathfrak{m}_{\mathfrak{p}}$ is the unique prime/maximal ideal of the localisation $\mathcal{O}_{K,\mathfrak{p}}$, and $\pi$ is a uniformizer.
Let $\sigma \in \operatorname{Gal}(K/\mathbb{Q})$. I need to prove that the following conditions are equivalent:
(1) $\sigma(x) \equiv x \operatorname{mod} \mathfrak{p}^{i+1}$ for all $x \in \mathcal{O}_K$ ($\sigma$ is in the $i^{th}$ ramification group $V_i$);
(2) $\sigma(y)\equiv y \operatorname{mod} \mathfrak{m}_\mathfrak{p}^{i+1} $ for all $y \in \mathcal{O}_{K,\mathfrak{p}}$;
(3) $\sigma(\pi) \equiv \pi \operatorname{mod} \mathfrak{m}_\mathfrak{p}^{i+1} $.
I do not know where to start with the equivalence (1)$\iff$ (2).
The implication (2) $\implies$ (3) is rather trivial (just let $y=\pi$).
As for (3) $\implies$ (2), I assume we should use the fact that every element $y \in \mathcal{O}_{K,\mathfrak{p}}$ can be written in the form $y=u\pi^k$ for some unit $u\in \mathcal{O}_{K,\mathfrak{p}}^\times$.
How would one go about proving these equivalences?
